# Conformal angle transformation

Tags: conformal-field-theory, geometry

As I understand a conformal transformation transforms the metric $g_{mn}\rightarrow f^2(x)g_{mn}$ for some function $f$ that is non-zero everywhere.

> Why does this preserve angles?

I know that $\cos\alpha=\frac{g_{mn}x_my_n}{\sqrt{x^2y^2}}$, so $\cos\tilde{\alpha}=\frac{f^2(x)g_{mn}\tilde{x}_m\tilde{y}_n}{\sqrt{\tilde{x}^2\tilde{y}^2}}$. But how do vectors transform?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as written, it is a pure math question, and is a duplicate of e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/693088/143136 on math.SE.

Comment: However on math.SE they only treat the 2D case